# Update data in one table with data from another table with some string manipulation

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation

I have two database tables as follows:

```
content_definition
(
    content_definition_id bigint ,
    content_title character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    content_desc character varying(500),
    content_kwd character varying(300),
    content_view_url character varying(100),
    content_edit_url character varying(300),
    content_media_url character varying(300),
    content_type character varying(50),
    site_id integer
)

bl_address
(
    address_id bigserial NOT NULL,
    entity character varying(30),
    entity_id integer,
    address1 character varying(150),
    address2 character varying(50),
    city character varying(50),
    state character varying(50),
    zip character varying(15),
    country character varying(50),
)
```

I am trying to create a SQL statement to update the `content_view_url` column in the first table by appending the data in it with `state` in the second table. The `content_id` in the first table should be equal to the `entity_id` in the second table. Also, I need to include `-` between the two strings that are being appended and also need to replace all the spaces in the state column with `-` and convert it to lower case since the data is a URL.

I tried to create a sample query using the `concat` function , but it is not working for me:

```
update content_definition 
set content_view_url = CONCAT(select content_view_url 
                              from content_definition, '-test') 
where content_definition_id = 770764;
```

I get error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 64

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: _"it is not working for me"_ please describe how it is "not working".

Comment: Your query has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions, the query that I was looking for is :

```
update content_definition cd
    set content_view_url = content_view_url || '-' || lower(replace(a.state, ' ' , '-'))
    from bl_address a
    where cd.content_id = a.entity_id and cd.content_type = 'business.location' and cd.site_id = 35;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can use a `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE`.  Based on the query in your question:

```
update content_definition cd
    set content_view_url = cd2.content_view_url || '-test'
    from content_definition cd2
    where cd2.content_definition_id = 770764;
```

Based on the question:

```
update content_definition cd
    set content_view_url = content_view_url || a.state
    from bl_address a
    where cd.content_id = a.entity_id;
```

Or based on your comment:

```
    set content_view_url = content_view_url || '-' || replace(a.state, ' ', '-')
```

Comment: is there a way to do the string operations like replacing space with - and add a - between the appended data.

Comment: @GeoThomas : Yes , everything to the right of the `=` is supposed to be a string expression, you can use any valid combination of string {objects, operators,functions} to construct it

Comment: @joop, I have created the query as update content_definition cd
    set content_view_url = content_view_url || '-' || lower(a.state)
    from bl_address a
    where cd.content_id = a.entity_id and cd.content_type = 'bl' and cd.site_id = 35; with the hep of the comments above. I am unable to figure out how to include the replacing the space with - before appending the data

Comment: I have figured it out, update content_definition cd
    set content_view_url = content_view_url || '-' || lower(lower(replace(a.state, ' ' , '-')))
    from bl_address a
    where cd.content_id = a.entity_id and cd.content_type = 'business.location' and cd.site_id = 35; is the query that I want